# How to find Arduino connected to FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, usb, tty, arduino

I have programmed Arduino to respond simple commands via USB. Unfortunately, I can't find it and can't communicate with it.

My `usbconfig` returns following:

```
$usbconfig
ugen1.1: <UHCI root HUB Intel> at usbus1, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen0.1: <UHCI root HUB Intel> at usbus0, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen4.1: <EHCI root HUB Intel> at usbus4, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen3.1: <UHCI root HUB Intel> at usbus3, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen2.1: <UHCI root HUB Intel> at usbus2, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=SAVE (0mA)
ugen3.2: <USB-Serial Controller Prolific Technology Inc.> at usbus3, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=ON (100mA)
ugen2.2: <USB2.0-Serial vendor 0x1a86> at usbus2, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=ON (96mA)
```

Is there Arduino among above?

When I try something like

```
screen /dev/ugen2.2
```

I have `screen` exiting immediatedly.

**UPDATE**

Experimentally I found that

```
ugen3.3: <USB2.0-Serial vendor 0x1a86> at usbus3, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=FULL (12Mbps) pwr=ON (96mA)
```

appears and disappears according to whether I have connected arduino or not.

Unfortunately command

```
screen /dev/ugen2.3 9600
```

exits with saying

```
'/dev/ugen3.3' is not a tty                                                                                                                                     Sorry, could not find a PTY or TTY.
```

Comment: Are you using serial over USB? Then the device node you need is `/dev/ttyU0`

Comment: I don't know what I am using. Arduino has USB socket and while programming on windows, it was visible as `COM5` port. No software was unstalled on FreeBSD. When connecting to `ttyU0` I see garbage constantly printing. This is probably USB GPS device working which is probably connected to first port. Is it possible to identify connected devices in FreeBSD programmatically?

Comment: You may see garbage because you chose wrong port speed. As for identifying devices, try using `usbconfig` utility.

Answer (score 0):

Try `kldload uftdi` (according to internet research arduino uses FTDI serial chips) or `kldload uplcom` (Your output reported an Prolific serial adapter) to get a tty. Later use screen on  /dev/ttyU0 as written in the comments

Another choice is to install `uarduno` if it is an arduino Uno

Answer (score 0):

An Arduino Uno will show as `/dev/cuaU0`. You might have to change the board ID in ids.txt to 0x0043. You need to add yourself (the user) to the dialer group for this to work, too. Don't forget to login/logout for that to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

usbconfig -d ugen3.2 dump_device_desc

Read the following for a helpful example of connecting USB Serial to FreeBSD with explanations on the uftdi connection to Crystal Fontz LCD display.   You need a uarduno kernel module to connect to a Arduino UNO board.

https://www.tnpi.net/computing/freebsd/crystalfontz.shtml

**Commands to Issue**

```
kldstat
kldload ucom umodem usb_template uarduno
sysctl hw.usb.template
sysctl hw.usb.template=3 
sysctl hw.usb.template
kldstat 
pstat -t
ls -l /dev
```

**Examples:**

```
#sudo sysctl hw.usb.template=3
hw.usb.template: -1 -> 3

sudo vi /boot/loader.conf
#add 5 lines for next boot to include modules
umodem_load="YES"
usb_template_load="YES"
ucom_load="YES"
uarduno_load="YES"
hw.usb.template=3
cu -s 9600 -l /dev/ttyU0
```

**URLS to look up**

https://wiki.freebsd.org/Arduino/NativeCLI

https://codeberg.org/FreeBSD/freebsd-ports/src/branch/main/comms/uarduno

https://www.freshports.org/comms/uarduno/

https://pkgs.org/download/uarduno

https://www.google.com/search?q=freebsd+uarduno&oq=freebsd+uarduno&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13i512j69i64.4660j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1

https://imin.red/2021/05/12/compile-esp8266-esp32-arduino-code-with-gmake-on-freebsd/